# Change Theme Color at Runtime in Android

Tags: java, android, android-theme

Theme colors can be changed if multiple themes added in app and can be switched at run time easily. Other way is to change the color of actiobar, textview etc one by one of all the object. This way is very long and take lots of code. Simple way i found is to change colors declare in colors.xml file but i could not find a way programmatically or third party library to do that. Is there a way to do this.

My Colors XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#ea1e63</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
</resources>
```

I just want to change **colorPrimary** color at runtime, this will change color on all app activities. I found https://github.com/negusoft/GreenMatter, to change colors at runtime but its old and dont work with android studio.

Comment: do you want to change color on any event (button click) ? @Burhan

Comment: doesn't matter, just change color on activity load or button click.

Comment: @Burhan did you find any answer to this solution?? I also want to do this particular thing !!

Comment: Well its not possible directly but i found third party library called green matter. Check that on github.

Answer (score 0):

when you apply theme and want to change color than

EX :

```
activity.setTheme(R.style.green);


<style name="green">
        <item name="main_background">@drawable/background_green</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="button_light">@color/button_light</item>
</style>
```

**theme color can not be change at runtime of a particular theme**.

Make custom style and change these styles when you want to change color in your application.

Comment: please read the question carefully, i dont want to switch theme at run time. I want to change color value save in color.xml file

Comment: check updated answer @Burhan

Comment: brother you are not understanding my question fully, what you are posting is called theme switching. What i want is that to change color in xml file. i.e
colorPrimary=#ea1e63 and i want colorPrimary=#000000. Without adding this in xml file. In short i want to change  colorPrimary with java(programatically) at runtime. Tell me is there a method to set colorPrimary at runtime

Comment: yourView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#fffff"));  this what you want @Burhan

Comment: Please read my question carefully! if i do this yourView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#fffff")); than i have to change color of every object one by one. But i change color in xml file than i dont need to instantiate every object. it will save lots of code

Comment: There is always a way to do

Comment: i tried helping you but you dont thing that usefull. @Burhan

Comment: info you told me is already on all forums and i know it, you ask questions on stackoverflow after you find no content according to your problem.

Comment: this is what i know and so told you. i have tried to give you best solution but got this result written in answer. @Burhan

Comment: "can't be" is not acceptable answer ;)  better write comment with "I don't know".