# Override style color programmatically

Tags: android, colors, styles

This is how my `style.xml` looks like:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#2196F3</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1976D2</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
    ...........
</style>
```

I want to override the `"colorPrimary"` and `"colorAccent"` programmatically (using `java`) from Appliation class or Activity class. Can anyone help me how I can make it possible?

Note: I don't want to create multiple `style.xml` files for different themes. I just want to override the basic colors programmatically e.g. I want to `"colorPrimary"` to `#FF0000` from `#2196F3`.

Comment: AFAIK its not possible to change only colors . You can have a look int this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34735500/change-theme-color-at-runtime-in-android).

Comment: Why don't you just change the colours in style.xml?

Comment: Because I need dynamic colors themes for different users, who can dynamically create it, not select from few options.